# Copying Folders with Wildcards

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy a whole bunch of files using Powershell, from one directory to another on my computer.

I used `Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Tom\Google Drive\My Files\*\Assessment 1\*` to identify that this was the path that I wanted to copy too, and I know about `Copy-Item`, but I want to maintain parts of the path name when copied.

Example:

If I copy from `C:\Users\Tom\Google Drive\My Files\Cool Stuff\Assessment 1\*`
I want the files to go to a folder that is created called `C:\Users\Tom\Archive\Cool Stuff\Assessment 1`

Whereas if I copy from `C:\Users\Tom\Google Drive\My Files\New Stuff\Assessment 1\*`

I want the files to go to a folder that is created called `C:\Users\Tom\Archive\New Stuff\Assessment 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to recursively find all `Assessment 1` folders within your base directory and then remove the base path using `-replace` to finally copy the items using the `Copy-Item` cmdlet:

```
$baseDir = 'C:\Users\Tom\Google Drive\My Files\'
$destination = 'C:\Users\Tom\Archive\'

Get-ChildItem $baseDir -directory -Filter 'Assessment 1' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $newPath = Join-Path $destination ($_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($baseDir))
    Copy-Item $_.FullName $newPath -Force -Recurse

}
```